# How to suspend and resume a std::thread?

Tags: stdthread

I am looking for a way of suspending & resuming a thread that is presented as a `std::thread` without using platform provided API, such as `SuspendThread` & `ResumeThread` on Windows. Note, the thread should only be suspended and resumed by other thread.

Comment: As of this writing, there is no such facility in the standard library. Suspending threads is generally a bad idea, since you might suspend it while it holds a lock.

Comment: think you have another target, and you think that suspend/resume can help here. but better ask about initial problem